# How to delete a specific type of files after x amount of days?

Tags: vb.net, find, backup, delete-file

I have a service that produces .txt files to a folder every 30 seconds. Is there anyway to delete files that are older than x amount of days?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that. Do you have an actual programming question?

Answer (score 1):

In your service you can loop through the list of files, find the ones that are x number of days old and delete them.

See the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx), [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx), [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) and [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) classes on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [WMI service](http://vbscriptblog.com/vbscript/wmi/files-wmi/vbscript-and-wmi-vbscript-to-find-files-with-specific-extensions-and-creation-date-on-remote-servers/) to find a collection of files with a certain creation date. Then delete them.